# Python Trim Multiple Column Names of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame of 20 columns. All of them have a common text and a serial number. I want to trim the text part and make the name shorter. Below is an example:

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame({'Column1':[10,20],'Column2':[80,90]})

   Column1  Column2
0       10       80
1       20       90
```

Expected output:

```
        C1       C2
0       10       80
1       20       90
```

Solution1:

```
oldcols = ['Column1','Column2']
newcols = ['C1','C2']
xdf.rename(columns=dict(zip(oldcols,newcols)),inplace=True)

        C1       C2
0       10       80
1       20       90
```

Solution2:

```
for i in range(len(oldcols)):
    xdf.rename(columns={'%s'%(xdf[i]):'%s'%(xdf[i].replace('Column','C'))},inplace=True)

raise KeyError(key) from err
```

Solution1 works fine but I have to prepare an old and new column names list. Instead, I want to iterate through each column name and replace the column text. However, solution2 is not working.

Comment: Do they all start with the common name and end with a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `str.findall` on the columns to split into text and number; then use a list comprehension to take only the first letter and join it with the numbers for each column name:

```
xdf.columns = [x[0]+y for li in xdf.columns.str.findall(r'([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)') for x,y in li]
```

Output:

```
   C1  C2
0  10  80
1  20  90
```

Comment: Your code nailed it. It is hard for me to understand what is going on there. How do we trim the column name `Column.1.2` to `1.2`? `x[0]+y` each stands for `x[0]` for `C` and `y` for `1 or 2`. Correct?

Comment: @Mainland correct. To split `Column.1.2` to `C1.2`, we could replace `([A-Za-z]+)(\d+)` with `([A-Za-z.]+)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` in the expression. What's happening is, we're splitting each string into 2 groups: letters (`([A-Za-z]+)`) and numbers (`(\d+)`).

Comment: yes, it worked. if you could explain, what the `+`, `?:`, `?` signs are doing here? Other were understood.

Comment: I have a question: in the above example, there is another column we don't want to rename. For example, `Fixed_col`. How do we keep it like this. We cannot use `xdf.columns = ` as in your solution. So, we want to rename the columns from `['Column1','Column2','Fixed_col']` to `['C1','C2','Fixed_col']`.

Comment: @Mainland you could `set_index('Fixed_col')`, change column names; then `reset_index`. As to your earlier question: `+` matches the preceding element 1 or more, `?` matches at most 1, `?:` matches but doesn't capture a group; you can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).